# Spectrum of a $1$-parameter family of symmetric linear operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am working with certain submanifolds of symmetric spaces and, using a construction in Terng-Thorbergson, we ended up in the following Hilbert space problem:

Let $H$ be a (real) Hilbert Space and $T_t:H \rightarrow H$ be a smooth $1$-parameter family of symmetric linear operators (and we can assume that those operators are defined in the whole space). Suppose that there is a finite-dimensional subespace $V$ of $H$ such that the spectrum of both $T_t$ and $T_t|_{V^\perp}$ does not depend on $t$, in the sense that the spectrum of $T_t$ and  $T_s$ for all $t,s \in \mathbb{R}$ are the same (similarly for $T_t|_{V^\perp}$) .

Is it true that the trace of $T_t|_V$ also does not depend on $t$?

Comment: Is $V$ a $T_t$-invariant subspace of $H$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Actually, no.

Comment: Then what do we mean by the spectrum of $T_t \vert_V : V \to H$?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, I am pretty sure he means the spectrum of the composition $pr_V T_t|_V:V\to V$, where $pr$ stands for orthogonal projection. Thinking on a matrix (choosing a basis for $V^\perp$, followed by one of $V$), the two restrictions corresponds to the square blocks related to $V^\perp$ and $V$